# File upload using drag drop in core Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want file upload using drag drop in core Asp.Net not in MVC. The size of the file may be bigger than the normal file like 100-200 MB. Please give me some solution in Asp.Net.

I am also looking for some third party tool. Please suggest me the good third party tools for file upload using drag drop.

Comment: Firstly I would google about HTML5 drag and drop features, then implement  a html helper class. Obviously not all browsers support html5 so you would need to fall back on a normal browse control.

Answer (score 0):

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ supports drag and drop.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.

Is this work with the Asp.net. And please suggest me the third party tools.

Comment: You can find example code for an ASP.NET implementation in the wiki-section. I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean with "third party tools".

Comment: Third party tools like telerik. Which create that kind of control and sell that controls.